# Use domain purchased in Azure outside of Azure

Tags: domains, azure

I purchased not that long ago a domain through Azure, but I would like to use it on Bluehost.

Is it possible to forward the domain on Azure portal or somehow bind my website on Bluehost with the domain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Register new hosting IP in DNS A Record](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88407/register-new-hosting-ip-in-dns-a-record)

Comment: It isn't clear whether you want all services moved to bluehost (i.e. change the nameservers) or just the website (change the A record).  No matter, bith questions have been answered before many times